# How to populate c++11 std::map<std::string,std::bitset<N>*> concurrently (thread-safe) without memory leakage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-leaks, mutex

Basically, I need to populate a `std::map` with millions of key entries (orders of 50 million more or less) from thousands of files that are read concurrently. The value that these keys will point to will be allocated from heap (`std::bitset` type).

```
std::map<std::string,std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>*> my_map;
```

1. My 1st concern is: I do not want two threads (that first check if a
   key exists and if it does not,) allocate space from heap.
   Because I only can hold one pointer and the other allocations would
   lead to memory leakage since I can't keep track of them.

   ```
   //count should be thread-safe, since it's defined as const in <map> header file
   if(my_map.count(key) == 0){
       //some other thread may have initialized the key in the mean time
       my_map[key] = new std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>();
       //Now I will lose the pointer to previous heap allocation from other thread
   }
   ```

   One solution would be to have some mutex mechanism like
   `boost::unique_lock` or some smart combination of `boost::shared_lock`
   and boost::unique_lock for the sake of performance,  which I'd be happy to hear your ideas.
2. Imagining I'm done with the first part, meaning; initializing keys of my_map without memory leakage concurrently, Second part of the quest is to manipulate the values (`std::bitset`) concurrently. To this end, I assume there should not be any problem since it's guaranteed no two threads will be working on the same key at the same time according to my setup. (No new keys will be added or keys removed from the underlying tree structure for the keys of my_map by any of the threads)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>*` instead of just a `std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>`?

Comment: I want to be able to keep this map and bitset for the entire life of the program, and I assume it should be allocated from heap since once the scope of the threaded function goes out, I can no longer trust the bitset allocated on the stack for that function.

Comment: Usually there is no reason for a pointer inside a map. Can you please double check if you absolutely need it? You won't need the original memory address of a bitset when you insert it in the map. The map is accessible by everyone, hence, the bitset will be accessible by everyone. Also, if it is guaranteed that two threads won't access the same key, then there won't be any memory leakage as well.

Comment: @SorooshBateni Well in the first phase there is no such guarantee so memory leakage can occur! Imagine I have a bunch of files that are read concurrently and for simplicity, each file has lines of the format:
key -> metadata .
same key can appear in all those files. but I just want to insert the key to map and associate a bitset for it only once it has been seen for the first time. If another thread reads the same key from another file, after the first occurrence, simply it is ignored! Now if two threads come across the same key which does not exist, I would have leakage issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` access to a `std::` container (like `map`) is guaranteed to be legal from different threads even without synchronization.

Any non-`const` access without synchronization makes any other access (`const` or non-`const`) illegal (the programs behavior becomes undefined).

Some operations are *not* `const`, but as far as synchronization are concerned is `const`.  For example, non-const `find` is treated "as `const`", as is `[]` on a `vector`.

`[]` on a map isn't `const` and isn't treated as `const`.  I am unsure if `[]` that does not create an element is treated as `const`, I would have to double-check the standard.  And as `find` exists and solves the same problem with well defined semantics, I wouldn't use it in code in any case.

`const` doesn't mean *thread-safe*, it means *thread-safe with other `const` operations*.  Thread-safe is a relation between two or more bits of code, it isn't an absolute.  So calling `.count` while someone else is inserting is not legal.

In general, sharing is the bane of thread safety.  The easier way to solve this would be to give each "task" its own `map` to work with.  Then you merge these `map`s back into a master map.

How complex and how often that merging happens becomes a matter of the specific application and how much replication there is.

The easiest solution is:

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>>>
parse_file( some_file_handle );
```

then

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>>>
parse_files( gsl::span<some_file_handle> handles ) {
  if (handles.size()==0) return {};
  if (handles.size()==1) return parse_file(handles.front());
  auto lhs = parse_files( handles.first(handles.size()/2) );
  auto rhs = parse_files( handles.last(handles.size()-handles.size()/2) );
  return merge_maps(std::move(lhs), std::move(rhs));
}
```

gives us our single-threaded version.  We multithread it by:

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>>>
parse_files( gsl::span<some_file_handle> handles, executor exec ) {
  if (handles.size()==0) return {};
  if (handles.size()==1) return parse_file(handles.front());
  auto lhs = exec( [handles]{parse_files(handles.first(handles.size()/2) )} );
  auto rhs = exec( [handles]{parse_files(handles.last(handles.size()-handles.size()/2) )} );
  auto retval = exec( [lhs=std::move(lhs], rhs=std::move[rhs]]()mutable{
    return merge_maps(std::move(lhs).get(), std::move(rhs).get() );
  }
  return std::move(retval).get();
}
```

where `executor` is takes an object of type `T()` and return a `future<T>`.  The naive executor simply runs the function and returns a ready future.  A fancier executor uses `std::async` to thread it off.  An even fancier one uses a thread pool, and when waited upon uses the waiting thread to run the task if it isn't already running.

Now, concurrency libraries like ppl or Intel's TBB provide ways to do this pretty easily.

Comment: Yeah, one solution could be a divide and conquer type of procedure and try to merge local maps and simply free the memory allocated in heap from either of lhs or rhs if they both have the same key. Others have also suggested Intel TBB, or mutex infrastructure by boost, but I'd like to have minimal dependency and only stick to c++11 standard library.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first - const function is not thread-safe. Consider:

```
struct A {
  int q;
  void set(int qq) { q = qq; }
  int get() const { return q; }
};
```

get() is not thread-safe - on the other thread set might be called, which will modify q. If you want thread-safety, you must either lock or update using atomic structures (there're other multithreading issues, which will happen if you dont lock / use atomics, but those are out of scope of your questions - you absolutely need either of those!).

Now to solution:
since you need to explicitly synchronize access to your map structure your problem becomes non-issue:

```
std::mutex m; // since c++11
...
{
    std::lock_guard _l(m); // since c++11
    if (!my_map.emplace(key, bitset_ptr).second)
        delete bitset_ptr;
}
```

this will insert element into *my_map* with key *key* and value *bitset_ptr*, but only if it doesnt exist. It will return tuple of two elements - first being iterator to either created element and previously existing and second being boolean flag, which will be true, if element was created and false if it existed before. So you simply delete *bitset_ptr* if element was already insterted and no memory leak for you. Note, that due to amount of synchronization this might be slow.

UPDATE:
you obviously need to synchronize using mutex m any access to my_map as long as you keep updating in multiple threads.

UPDATE2:
op has tried the easiest solution and found it not fast enough. Let's go deeper. (Note: the most optimal course of action is to measure performance of the application and find, where code is spending most of its time, but i cant do that ;)). There're few "obvious" (read: probable) causes of slowdown:

- inserting into map - insterting into sorted map has O(ln n) runtime performance and in reality might be very slow due to cache mismatches. in 1 milion elements map on average you will need to compare against 10 different string, lying (probably) in completely different areas of memory, thus purging each other from processor cache all the time.
- reading from files - reading small chunks from multiple files might (or might not!) be unhealthy to the overall speed.
- multiple allocations - in general memory allocation is slow. Also lot of allocations increase memory fragmentation and decrease locality.
- locking for synchronization - this aint healthy for anything...

I'll assume, that you cant easily (cheaply) determine amount of elements, that are in single file and in total. First the code:

```
using etype = pair<string, bitset<N>*>;
vector<etype> all_elements;
mutex all_elements_mutex;
void parse_single_file_in_thread(...) {
    vector<etype> tmp;
    for(auto element : parse_element_from_file()) 
        tmp.push_back(move(element));
    lock_guard _l(all_elements_mutex);
    for(auto &a : tmp) all_elements.push_back(move(a));
}
map<string, bitset<N>*> parse_all_files() {
    // create threads, parse files in them and wait for them to finish
    std::sort(all_elements.begin(), all_elements.end(), 
        [](const etype &a, const etype &b) { return a.first < b.first; });
    map<string, bitset<N>*> tmp;
    for(auto &a : all_elements) if (!tmp.insert(tmp.end(), etype(move(a.first), a.second)).second) delete a.second;
    all_elements.clear();
    return tmp;
}
```

What it does is few things:
- insert keys into vector first (ignore checking for duplicates), later on this will be sorted and inserted into map with placement hint (they are sorted, so we always know correct place to insert next element - end of the map), this is MUCH faster, than directly inserting into map
- every file's items are first put into it's own vector and moved into global one after parsing whole file, this minimizes locking

This should be enough for performance gain. Next thing would be replace string with something else to avoid so many string to string sorting comparisions. But this would get out of scope easily. ;)

Note: i've written whole code from memory, so it might not compile and it might require c++17.

Comment: So, I guess I misunderstood what the const member function entails. I knew it's the way of saying that member function does not mess with the state of the object at all. But, I read somewhere explaining the difference between [] operator and std::map::at or count and maybe mistakenly they have mentioned it is thread-safe because it's const. locking does not give as much performance as I need, running on a single thread with test data takes 25 minutes with 6 threads it takes 14 minutes.